# How Can I Put Chrome App Files On Github Without Files?

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome, github, google-chrome-app

I would like to make a chrome app into an android app with PhoneGap Build, and I would like to put my chrome app on Github. The problem is, I can't because I don't have the files. I accidentally deleted them permanently one time. I do have access to the developer dashboard, but I haven't been able to find a way to download files from it. Help, please! I have tried pressing ctrl+shift+s after opening the chrome app. I have no idea what I'm doing now. Help will be wonderful!

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin?hl=en

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for, @DanielHerr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to download the .crx file from the developer dashboard, its buried under the "More Info" link in the right side of the page.  But then you have a .zip file that has additional headers and its not obvious how to unzip.

The easiest way is to install the app through the developer dashboard (click the link of the name of the app).  Next, run the app.  Then use chrome extensions page (Under main chrome menu More Tools > Extensions, or navigate straight to chrome://extensions), enable Developer Mode, then scroll down to the app and click the link to its index page which will load Chrome Developer tools for the running app.  You can get at all the HTML, JavaScript, and CSS for the app.  See screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm extremely impressed by this method! Good job! How can this work for images?

Comment: I added an screenshot of how to get at images to the answer.  In the dev tools, go to Network tab and filter by "Img"